# Extract data in the order they're shown in the listview

Tags: wpf, listview

I have a listview and it can be ordered by clicking on the column's header, but how can I extract the elements in the same order they are shown in the listview?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (int x = 0; x < listView1.Items.Count; x++)
{
    if (listView1.Items[x].Selected)
    {
        string cc = listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[2].Text;
    }
}
```